# How to obtain similar result as virtual function template c++

Tags: c++, templates

Here's my issue, I'm trying to create a base class which can get a reference to a queue member in a derived class. I have two template functions in my base class :

```
class Base
{
    template<TYPE type>
    virtual void foo(std::queue<TYPE>*& typeQueue) //I know virtual isn't allowed
    {
        //do nothing as it's general case
    }

    template<typename TYPE>
    void bar(TYPE type)
    {
        std::queue<TYPE>* typeQueue;
        foo(typeQueue);
        //... do some stuff with type
    }
}
```

and a derived class which would theoretically be able to specialize the function `foo` for any types

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:

    template<>
    void foo<int>(std::queue<int>*& m_integerQueue)
    {
        integerQueue= &m_integerQueue;
    }

    template<>
    void foo<double>(std::queue<double>*& doubleQueue)
    {
        doubleQueue = &m_doubleQueue;
    }

private:

    std::queue<int> m_integerQueue;
    std::queue<double> m_doubleQueue;
}
```

code above is more of about an ideology then a code to take word for word, I'd like the function `bar` to call the according function `foo` in derived class based on the type specified when `bar` is called. Of course this solution isn't working and the problem here is that we can't make template functions virtual.

I'm not sure if it's an error of design, but that's the general idea and I couldn't find an appropriate solution anywhere so I posted my own question here.

*EDITED to make my problem clear*

Comment: An alternative to having many virtual functions in your interface is the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). It works with function templates well. Of course it has downsides of its own.

Comment: You have comment `//I know this isn't allowed`, so why did you write `foo` this way? What is wrong with `template<typename TYPE>
    void foo(TYPE type)`?

Comment: [By the way](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=virtual+template).

Comment: @mvidelgauz it's the `virtual` part which isn't allowed, but `template<typename TYPE> void foo(TYPE type)` would not work as `bar` would always call his version of `foo` and not the specialized ones

Comment: Whenever this type of question is asked, it's quite evident the OP thinks this is a solution to some design problem. So why not ask about the original problem directly?

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What's the real problem you are trying to solve?